# How to move left div to the top of website when window size gets smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to move my image div which is originally on the left side of my webpage to the top of the page when the window resizes reaches to a certain width.

```
.image {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 55vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("signup.jpeg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 55vw 100vh;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    order: 2;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the image should be `flex`. The container that contains the image should be `flex` so it can adjust the image position based on its other child elements.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We can't possible answer your question as it stands and I'm surprised that the filters let it through

Comment: Please stop deleting your code. If you want to close the question, do that. Mangling a post isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  order: 1; /* Initial order, displays on the left */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 55vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("signup.jpeg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 55vw 100vh;
}

.content {
  order: 2; /* Initial order, displays on the right */
  /* Other styles for the content div */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    order: 2; /* Change order to 2, moves to the top */
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .content {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1; /* Change order to 1, moves below the image */
    /* Other styles for the content div in smaller screens */
  }
}
```

By using the order property along with flexbox and media queries, you can control the order and layout of elements based on different screen sizes.

Comment: So when I do this I have the image div on the right side and the content div on the left. Ive edited my post to show what I put so far

Answer (score 0):

several small problems in your code no closing }, double width...

as saying Andy, flex is not necessary
just put the image position absolute in body

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 55vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .image {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 55vh;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```